Public flight from Quito (UIO) to Lago Agrio Airport (LGQ)
I would like to visit to Cuyabeno Wildlife Reserve (Reserva de producción de fauna Cuyabeno). The fastest way would be to fly from Quito's Mariscal Sucre International Airport (UIO) to Lago Agrio Airport (LGQ).
Although Mariscal Sucre International Airport web shows flights from/to to Lago Agrio Airport operated EP Petroecuador (listed as Government airlines). But I was not able to find any info about flights on company website https://www.eppetroecuador.ec/. I suppose there is no public flight to Lago Agrio Airport right?

WikiVoyage indicates that Avianca flies to it however searching for LGQ on Avianca's website leads to nothing. So there indeed doesn't seem to be a public flight still operating.
Your best bet is probably to take a coach to Lago Agrio
Two coach services leave overnight from Quito TransEsmeraldas and Cooperativa Banos

Google Flights doesn't even know LGQ, so it's quite likely there is no public service to that airport at all. Flightradar24 doesn't recognise it either. Flightaware lists a few days with a few flights back in March and nothing since then.
Petroecuador is the national oil company of Ecuador, so they probably just operate their own private flights there.
Google Maps shows a photo from March 2023 of an Aeroregional aircraft in LGQ, but it's not listed as a destination on their website at this time.
There is however another airport in El Coca (OCC), less than 2 hours away by road.
But Lago Agrio / Nueva Loja airport is less than 6 hours away from Quito by road, so it may be easier that way, especially since you need a vehicle to get to the reserve anyway.
There's actually another airport even closer (Tarapoa Airport, TPC), but it does not seem to have any public service either (probably even less than LGQ).
Note that while I understand how you get near the reserve, I have no idea how you get into it or to any of the lodges within. My impression is you get there by the river rather than by road. It would probably be a good idea to contact the lodge you want to stay at, they probably have better information on how to get there, and it's possible they arrange private flights to the most convenient airport, or arrange transportation from Quito via other means.
